# JSTL Message Bundle with Localized Parameter in Placeholder

Tags: java, spring, jsp, jstl

I'm using Spring and JSTL.

I have the following keys in a bundle (`messages.properties`):

```
key.withplaceholder= Never {0}.
key.giveup=give up
```

And I have the following code:

```
<fmt:message key="key.withplaceholder">
  <fmt:param value="lie"/>
</fmt:message>
```

With this code I can show the message:

> Never lie.

But if I want to use the `key.giveup` to show `"Never give up"` I don't know how to do it. How can I accomplish this?

Finally, is there a better way to do it? (without having to load a resource bundle in the jsp).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use the `var` attribute to store the formatted message in a page scoped variable instead of printing it out to the response.

```html
<fmt:message key="key.giveup" var="key" />
<fmt:message key="key.withplaceholder">
    <fmt:param value="${key}" />
</fmt:message>
```